# Is there a way to see the files size of a specific folder?

Tags: batch-file

i am a rookie in developing and i am trying to create a .bat file. When i run this file it will extract a .txt which will show the size of files of a specific folder.
For example, i have a folder "TEST" and contains 10 files. I want to know the size (measured in bytes) of these files.

I tried the following:

```
(@for /f "delims=" %%g in ('dir /b/s/a-d') do @echo %%~fg %%~zg) >C:\Users\Piers\Desktop\Filelist_size.txt
```

The problem i face is the following:
I have to run the .bat inside the folder that contains the files i want to check. If i try to run the bat from my Desktop for example, it will extract a .txt with all files of Desktop folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the folder you want as part of the `DIR` command.

```
dir C:\Myfolder /b/s/a-d
```

or

```
dir "C:\My folder with spaces" /b/s/a-d
```

Comment: Thank you for your help...too bad i didn't solve it myself :)